# how to bind two keys, like Control+z="<" with xev and xmodmap

Tags: shortcut-keys

Im trying to find how to something like :

Control+z="<" Control+x=">"

Is this possible? my keyboard doesnt have the ISO missing key that in Portuguese matches the <> key.

the keycode for <> key is 94, being that without shift is <(less) and with shift pressed is >(greater)

the keycode for control left is 37, Control_L the keycode for z is 52 and for x is 53.

How can i do this using xmodmap:

xmodmap -e "keycode 37 + keycode 52 = less" xmodmap -e "keycode 37 + keycode 53 = greater"

Comment: I was trying to map my "/" to "~" and "shift+/" to "?", but `xmodmap -e "keycode 50 + keycode 61 = question"` just remaped the left shift to "?", but this worked:  `xmodmap -e "keycode 61 = asciitilde question"`, https://askubuntu.com/a/855674/46437

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use xmacro instead, it seemed to work in this similar question:

[How to create a unicode combination of keys by pressing one key (Simplify unicode adding)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150122/how-to-create-a-unicode-combination-of-keys-by-pressing-one-key-simplify-unicod)