# How to remap key with shift and alt modifier using xmodmap?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I want to put have the following behaviour for key with code 94:

1. by default it is '<'
2. with <kbd>Shift</kbd> it is '>'
3. with <kbd>Alt</kbd> it is '|'

I only managed to get the default and <kbd>Shift</kbd>  behaviour by using command (names are from `xev`):

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = less greater"
```

I tried three thing to all of the behaviour:

1)

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 94 mod1 = less greater bar"
```

2. xmodmap -e "keycode 94 shift mod1 = less greater bar"
3. 

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = less greater"
xmodmap -e "add mod1 = less bar"
```

First two add the effect of having '<' by default and '|' with <kbd>Shift</kbd> . I'm not entirely sure what the third one did.

I also got the same behaviour as in 1) and 2) (<kbd>Shift</kbd> is relevant, <kbd>Alt</kbd> does nothing) from command:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 94 mod1 = less bar"
```

My information is mostly based [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/24930) (especially the bonus section).

How to map a single key to have a different default, shift and behaviour based on modifier(s)?

Comment: Maybe http://askubuntu.com/a/423245/16395 can help you. Notice that `xmodmap` is not recommended anymore in Ubuntu. You should use the more powerful (but a lot more complex) xkbd system... You can find links in the answer linked here

Answer (score 10):

Just found out, heuristically ! Look at the following :

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 38 = a A aacute Aacute ae AE ae"
```

It's basically

1. a: normal a
2. A: shift + a
3. á: altgr + a
4. Á: shift + altgr + a
5. æ: [some modifier combination] + a
6. Æ: shift + [some modifier combination] + a
7. æ: ???

So just reconfigure the key with the representations you want. For example, I reassigned period + altgr to interpunct (a bit expedient though):

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 60 = period greater 0x00b7 0x00b7 0x00b7 0x00b7"
```

Comment: kind of old, but how do you choose/ find out which modifier activate 5. and 6.? i can't make them trigger