# custom hot key for terminal command

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to hit <kbd>F1</kbd> and have a string with return key to be typed automatically into the terminal I am in.  I do not want to do it with `.bash_profile` because I want it to be configured locally in once place not on every server I `ssh` in to.

How do I do that?

Comment: I suggest you use xmacro, as seen in this reply:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/150122/how-to-create-a-unicode-combination-of-keys-by-pressing-one-key-simplify-unicod

Comment: Better yet, tell us what you are trying to do. There are better ways to automatize things than using xmacro.

Answer (score 3):

OK, the answer that I have and which works almost exactly as requested is actually surprisingly complex. You will use `xmacro` to record and play back key strokes.

1. Install xmacro

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xmacro
   ```
2. Record a macro

   ```
   xmacrorec2 > test.macro
   ```

   Now press <kbd>ESC</kbd> (to record the "abort" key for recording), type whatever text you want to assign and press <kbd>ESC</kbd>  again to stop the recording. The recorded macro is now in the file `test.macro`; you can edit it with a text editor.
3. Test that macro works

   ```
   cat test.macro | xmacroplay -d 0 $DISPLAY
   ```
4. (optional, recommended) Create a script with the above commands. Save it as macro.sh:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   cat test.macro | xmacroplay -d 0 $DISPLAY > /dev/null 2>/dev/null
   ```

   Make it executable:

   ```
   chmod a+x macro.sh
   ```
5. A little problem remains. xmacro plays back the exact keystrokes, but if you define a shortcut, and run the script from the shortcut, the keys will be played *before* you release the shortcut key, as if you started typing without releasing the key. You need to prepend the following line to the test.macro file:

   ```
   KeyStrRelease F1
   ```

   which will simulate the release of the F1 key.
6. Using keyboard preferences (you can access them through settings or by typing `gnome-control-center keyboard), create a new shortcut under "Custom shortcuts" and assign to it F1.

OK, but there is one more caveat: the F1 shortcut will now work in *every* application, not only the terminal. I don't know how to solve it; possibly, in the `macro.sh` one would have to test what window has the focus first and check whether the identifier of this window is terminal.