# Terminal: binding hotkeys to textual commands

Tags: gnome-terminal

Is there a way to bind hotkeys to textual commands in the terminal? For example: 
`ctrl+b == git branch <ret>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[You can use the bash `bind` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4120926/634853) as seen in the linked Stackoverflow answer.

In your case, the command would be:

```
bind '"\C-b":"git branch\n"'
```

To make it stick from session to session then add it to your `~/.inputrc`

[Bash bind reference.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins) (also available as `man bash`)

Comment: be aware that this approach may overwrite a default combination that is already assigned. You may check which bindings are in use with `bind -P`

Comment: also, for this particular case, `bind -x '"\C-b":"git branch"'` seems much better, as it will issue the command without affecting (or being affected by) your current command line

Comment: '\C' stands for Control, what stands for Alt?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a hotkey, how about a *bash alias*?

For example:

```
alias b='git branch'
```

now `b` is an alias for `git branch`, and you can simply type `b <ret>` in your terminal.

It is in a way much better than a hotkey, since you can still add other options to your command before hitting enter. For example:

```
b --all
b --remotes
b -m newbranch
```

... and so on.

To make this alias permanent, add it to the end of your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`. The latter is preferred, but only works if your ~/.bashrc sources it. The default one for Ubuntu 12.04 does.

You can check if a given command is already assigned to an alias, program, function or builtin using `type <command>`:

```
$ type b
b is aliased to `git branch'

$ type cp
cp is /bin/cp

$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin

$ type quote
quote is a function
quote () 
{ 
    echo \'${1//\'/\'\\\'\'}\'
}

$ type c
bash: type: c: not found
```

Last but not least, it is also worth checking availability for commands that does not exist *in your system*, but may exist in Ubuntu's repositories:

```
$ blender
The program 'blender' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install blender
```

This way your alias don't shadow any (current or future) command

Comment: That's a very good answer about aliases, but alas I don't want it to be an alias, specifically to take advantage of my right hand thumb.

Comment: @EpsilonVector: I fail to see why `CTRL`+`b` would be any different, "thumb-wise", than `b`+`ENTER`. Both are 2 keypresses. But hey, whatever floats your boat :P

Comment: Right after typing it's not different (you have to move your hand to the right to reach enter/ctrl), but in between typing ctrl is where my right thumb naturally rests.

Comment: @EpsilonVector: by the way... was `git branch` just an example or do you really just want to have a quick way to "know which branch you are" when using the terminal and browsing repositories? Because there are much better solutions for that using `PS1`

Comment: Just an example... But PS1 looks very useful. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

The best way would be to:

- Write a script with the command you want to execute
- Create a .desktop file for this .sh file
- Assign a shortcut key to this .desktop file

Comment: I'm sure this is not what the OP wants. He wants to issue the command in his *current* terminal, as if he copy and pasted it. Besides, writing a 1-line shell script for a `.desktop` file is silly: you can simply invoke your command directly in the `.desktop` file

Comment: Besides, for the particular command of `git branch` such desktop file is useless, since it always defaults to `$HOME` as its working directory, and there is no way to tell the desktop file where the repository is.

Comment: @MestreLion the reason why I mentioned script in my answer. The script can contain cd /path/where/git/resides command before the git command

Comment: @MestreLion if the question is about a shortcut for a command in the current terminal, bash alias would be adequate

Comment: A script containing a path to a specific git repository is not much better: it would be useful only for that single harcoded repo.

Answer (score 0):

A program like xmacro may be of help:

```
 xmacrorec can be used to record mouse and keyboard events on any X11 display.
 .
 xmacroplay can be used to playback recorded events or send any other
 mouse/keyboard events you choose. It is very handy for scripting an
 X display - for example controlling a presentation in mgp or ultrapoint
 from a script, network connection...
 .
 xmacroplay-keys is a script to help use the above.
```

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150122/how-to-create-a-unicode-combination-of-keys-by-pressing-one-key-simplify-unicod) and its answer for more details.